# Subtract a value from date & return new Date in Php

Tags: php

For eg if today is 13/08/18 so if i subtract 3 from this value it should return me 10/08/18 in PHP. Can any one help me. I have tried the following.

```
<?php
echo $old_date=3;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $today = date("d/m/y");   
echo $new_date = $today-$old_date;
?>
```

Comment: `$today = date("d/m/y")` -- `$today` is a partial text representation of the current time. You cannot subtract strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
$val=-3;
echo date_create('2011-04-24')->modify($val.'days')->format('Y-m-d');;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using following way.

```
$old_val=-3;
echo date('d/m/y', strtotime("$old_val days"));
```

**Output**

10/08/18

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime(date("d-m-y"));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P3D'));
echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";
```

This will work for your. You use the DateTime function of php and in the subtract part you remove 3 Days. In the last line you just format your date as you wish to be shown.

Output is:

*15/08/2013*

More info about dateTime you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use only 1 line:**

```
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-3 days'));
```

Comment: can you upvote the question @Squalo